# react-router-dom - Route not loading

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm refactoring some code to use `react-router-dom` and I don't understand why the Route component isn't loading. Upon successful login the user should be redirected to `/packages`, which they are, however the UI isn't updated and the `componentDidMount` api call is not firing.

***loginActions.js***

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import LoginApi from '../api/loginApi'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory()

export function loginUser(user) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return LoginApi.login(user).then(creds => {
      dispatch(loginUserSuccess(creds));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  }
}

export function loginUserSuccess(creds) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('credentials', JSON.stringify(creds.data));
  history.push('/packages');
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    state: creds.data
  }
}
```

***PackageContainer.jsx***

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {loadPackages} from '../../actions/packageActions'
import PackageList from './PackageList'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

class PackageContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(loadPackages()); // NOT FIRING
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-12">
        {this.props.results ?
        <PackageList results={this.props.results} /> :
        <h3>No Packages Available</h3>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PackageContainer.propTypes = {
  results: ImmutablePropTypes.list.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    packages: state.get('packages'),
    results: !state.getIn(['packages','packages','results']) ? List() : state.getIn(['packages','packages','results'])
  };
}

PackageContainer = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(PackageContainer))

export default PackageContainer
```

***App.jsx***

```
import LoginFormContainer from './components/Login/LoginFormContainer'
import PackageContainer from './components/Package/PackageContainer'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Navbar>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand><h3>Mythos</h3></Navbar.Brand>
          </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
        <Row className="content">
          <Col xs={12} md={12}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={LoginFormContainer} />
              <Route exact path='/packages' component={PackageContainer} />
            </Switch>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

***Edit***

Adding `historyApiFallback: true` to webpack config fixed the component not loading but still requires a page reload.

```
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    proxy: [{
      context: ['/idm', '/vsms'],
      target: 'http://vsdm-gw-dev.labviaaq.com'
    }],
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```